# Why is my disk suddenly full while du only shows (quite a bit) less space being used?

Tags: raspbian

On my Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 system it seems that I've run out of space.

`df` shows that no more space is available on the root filesystem:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       118G  118G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        430M     0  430M   0% /dev
tmpfs           462M     0  462M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           462M   13M  450M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           462M     0  462M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   49M  204M  20% /boot
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

When I check with `du -h`, the last line shows

```
77G
```

So where there should be some space left - what might be the problem?

Before I had a large log file (`/var/log/messages`) that I deleted (as it shows up in the `du` output), but now I don't understand why `df` still shows 100% in use.

Comment: What is currently reported by `sudo du -xhd1 /` and `df -h`

Comment: Strangely it seems to be okay again - but only after the *second* reboot (the formatting in this comment doesn't work):

    pi@slimpi:~ $ sudo du -xhd1 /
    4.0K    /srv
    16K     /lost+found
    32K     /tmp
    1.6G    /usr
    139M    /home
    75G     /media
    41M     /opt
    4.0K    /mnt
    762M    /var
    28K     /root
    4.2M    /etc
    78G     /

Comment: This will be informative: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/df-vs-du-why-so-much-difference

Comment: ...and, in addition to @Seamus's comment, further explanations (long and short) here: https://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/12/why-du-and-df-display-different-values.html

Comment: You might have run out of inodes, try `du -i` to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Summation: du is the better tool to use if you are interested in knowing how much space is actually being used on your filesystem "right now." df is great for "ballpark estimates" and is preferred if you need to know how big df thinks your filesystem is (so it will agree with other incorrect system statistics).

<sup>REFERENCE: [Why du & df Display Different Values](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/12/why-du-and-df-display-different-values.html)</sup>

The reference above is quite old now - nearly 14 yrs old as of this writing - but it's still a good, technically accurate and easy-to-understand explanation. If you're interested in more details, there are [many, many other references you can find for the cost of a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+du+vs+df).

#### `du` is the tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

The log file might still be open (so kept on disk), but not pointed to by any inode (so not findable by du).

You might have to reboot or restart the service that was logging to that file before the space is freed.